# Mouse button gets locked in java applications

Tags: 18.04, java, mouse, touchpad, gui

I'm running a relatively fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 on a new laptop. I have a couple of applications that I use that are written in Java -- specifically Aqua Data Studio and JetBrains Data Grip.

After a reboot, I can run one of these applications exactly one time without issue. SO for example, after a reboot I can run Data Grip, and it will work perfectly. At this point, one of several actions can trigger a change:

- I keep Data Grip running, and fire up an instance of Aqua Data Studio
- I close Data Grip, and fire up an instance of Aqua Data Studio
- I close Data Grip, and run a new instance of Data Grip

In any of those cases, I end up with what appears to be a stuck mouse. Sometimes it will seem to be stuck down (so moving the mouse around will either drag objects, or select text) or or stuck up (where I am unable to click on any target inside any of the Java windows).

When the mouse it stuck, the keyboard responds perfectly. If I Alt-Tab away to a different window, the mouse works 100% as expected. If I Alt-Tab back to the offending Java window, the mouse reverts back to the aberrant behavior that it was demonstrating previously.

Data Grip, I think, comes with an embedded java. Aqua Data Studio has the option to run either an embedded java, or the system java. Some versions will be available below.

I get the same results from the touchpad, or from a USB mouse.

```
$uname -a
Linux kirk-xps 4.15.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 13 08:44:47 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"

$ ./bin/datastudio-18.5/jre/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_102"

$ ./bin/datastudio_19/jre/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_102"

$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.28.2

$ dmesg | grep -i touchpad
[    7.047559] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: DLL07e6 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
[    7.102431] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.2, id: 0x1e2a1, caps: 0xf00323/0x840300/0x12e800/0x0, board id: 3038, fw id: 2375007
[    7.138451] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
[  110.568852] input: DELL07E6:00 06CB:76AF Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-7/i2c-DELL07E6:00/0018:06CB:76AF.0006/input/input27

$ free -m
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   
available
Mem:          15756        5038        5695        1981        5022       8835
Swap:           979           0         979
```

DataGrip is using Java 1.8.0_152.

Answer (score -1):

I am experiencing this problem too.  I had the problem in 18.04 and still have it in 20.04.

The app I see it in is JabRef.  The version I'm using is 5.2 and it has an embedded java, although I had this problem with the default install JabRef on both versions of Ubuntu.

```
$ ~/opt/JabRef/lib/runtime/bin/java --version
openjdk 15.0.1 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu15.28+51-CA (build 15.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu15.28+51-CA (build 15.0.1+9, mixed mode)
```

The behavior is exactly as you describe.  I will note that it doesn't start out this way but some errant mouse click will induce it and from then on it's stuck in that mode.

I've watched mouse events with xinput and xev after this issue is triggered and there are no additional events occurring when over the window, just regular mouse movement.  When I reach an element in the window that would normally respond to drag events that element starts acting as if drag event is in progress.

In the JabRef case, the drag event affects boundary placing and column selection in the app.  Closing the app and re-opening does nothing.   The only thing that seems to work is to restart the desktop, which is super annoying.

I suspect it has something to do with the window manager and java playing nice together.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this post. Since you have offered a guess at an explanation and stated that restarting fixes this temporarily, which is a sort of workaround, I'm not deleting this post, although it *might* be considered "not an answer" according to [this meta discussion](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17210/me-too-post-or-partial-answer). Since this isn't a new question, and I think you're seeking solutions, you may prefer to delete this and post it as a question instead, linking to this one for context. You can also *follow* this question to be notified of updates